# Is there any way to set zoom with ARCore camera?

Tags: android, kotlin, opengl, augmented-reality, arcore

I am working on an application where I need to take a frame every 30 frames.

I depend on this example:
https://github.com/NoorulHarishaN/Recording-and-Playback-API-ARCore/tree/master

**Configures the session with feature settings**

```
  private void configureSession() {
    Config config = session.getConfig();
    config.setLightEstimationMode(Config.LightEstimationMode.ENVIRONMENTAL_HDR);
    if (session.isDepthModeSupported(Config.DepthMode.AUTOMATIC)) {
      config.setDepthMode(Config.DepthMode.AUTOMATIC);
    } else {
      config.setDepthMode(Config.DepthMode.DISABLED);
    }
    if (instantPlacementSettings.isInstantPlacementEnabled()) {
      config.setInstantPlacementMode(InstantPlacementMode.LOCAL_Y_UP);
    } else {
      config.setInstantPlacementMode(InstantPlacementMode.DISABLED);
    }
    session.configure(config);
  }
```

So is there any way to set the zoom for the ARCore camera?